# How to move elements that are within the overflowing div with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to move elements that are within the overflowing div with Jquery command. Here I'm attaching the image. [image]

I attach the image of what I'm trying to implement. The blue dotted box has a red box that overflows the blue box(parent). I hope that the red box will move within the blue dotted box with Jquery.

```
        <div style="position:relative;">
          <div class="row" id='blue_box'
            style="overflow:scroll; overflow-y:hidden;
            width:100%; border:10px dotted blue;">
            <div id = 'red_box' class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"
              style="display:flex;justify-content:space-around;
              width:90vw; max-width:1296px; height:32vw; margin:10px;
              border: 1px solid red;">
              <div style="width:80vw;
                height:32vw;
                border:10px solid transparent;
                max-height:467px;">
              content..I want to move red box that is overflowing within the blue box..
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

How can I approach this problem? How can I use scrollTop(?) or scrollRight with which reference? I would love to eventually put the implemented function to the button (purple arrow)..

Please share your insight with me! I'm looking forward.

Comment: Using bootstrap for the html part?

Comment: is this approximately what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/0qtjj04m/1/

Comment: Hi, Ayan, nope. Your jsfiddle just renders the dotted box with red box. As you see my question, I already have this with the overflowing red box inside. When user scroll-down/up, the view moves to left/right. I want it to make this with jquery. By doing so, the user will click the button to make view move left/right.

Comment: So you want it to make it with pure jQuery only? And you want only the red box to be inside while rest of the content as it is?

Comment: I ran your code in fiddle and it seems that your red border is already inside the blue border. https://jsfiddle.net/ayan/m6s0u340/

Comment: Hi, Ayan! What I want to implement is "Jquery" part. I will create the button to make the red box move within the blue box. That's what my question is trying to solve ! (:

Comment: Ok, I see. So you can try something like a jquery carousel?

Comment: or may be you are looking for this `$(container).scrollTo(target);`

Comment: yes yes! But I don't know how to use in this situation, making the element move left and right. And also, the movement will not be 0% or 100% of the entire width, meaning the longer you press the button, the more you will move the elements to the left! Do I deliver my situation clearly? (:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135448/discussion-between-ayan-and-sungpah-lee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the outline of a solution:

- When the user hits the move button (`mousedown`), initiate a programmatic scroll, at slow speed, to the right end of the inner pane.
- When the user stops holding down the mouse key (`mouseup`), stop the programmatic scroll.
- Make it work for touch-enabled devices, too, by adding the necessary events.

With [jQuery.scrollable](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.scrollable) (which I have written), this is a matter of just a few lines. Assuming a scroll container `#outer`, and controls for left and right movement (`#left` and `#right`), this is a working solution:

```
$( function () {
  
  var $container = $( "#outer" ),
      $left = $( "#left" ),
      $right = $( "#right" ),
      $both = $left.add( $right ),
      
      opts = { duration: 2000 };
  
  $left.on( "mousedown touchstart pointerdown", function () {
    $container.scrollTo( "left", opts );
  } );
           
  $right.on( "mousedown touchstart pointerdown", function () {
    $container.scrollTo( "right", opts );
  } );
  
  $both.on( "mouseup touchend pointerup", function ()  {
    $container.stopScroll();
  } );
  
  // Controls are inside the scrolling area, so exclude them
  // from automatic detection of user interaction, see
  // https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.scrollable#exceptions-for-selected-elements
  $both.on( "mousedown touchstart pointerdown", function ( event ) { 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
  } );
  
} );
```

Have a look at this [simplified demo](http://output.jsbin.com/segicul/2) ([code view](http://jsbin.com/segicul/2/edit?html,css,js,output)) to see it at work.